# Об употреблении словосочетаний "друг за другом" и "один за другим"

Tags: орфоэпия

Поговаривают, что указание "Возьми друг за другом туза и валета." означает указание "Возьми один за другим туза и валета.".

Какое из двух вышеперечисленных указаний орфоэпичнее другого?

Answer (score 4):

> Какое из двух вышеперечисленных указаний орфоэпичнее другого?

```
Я комнату взглядом окинул
И, будто узором прельщен,
«Мне нравятся очень… обои!» —
Сказал им и выбежал вон.

Понять моего каламбура
Из них ни единый не мог,
И долго стояли в раздумье
Студьозусы Вагнер и Кох.

©Козьма Петрович
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае должно быть "возьми одного за другим".

Одни словари фиксируют эти выражения как синонимы, другие различают значение одушевленности и неодушевленности. При этом во всех приводимых примерах *один за другим* относится и к одушевленным, и к неодушевленным сущ., а *друг за другом* - только к одуш.

1.Толковый словарь Ушакова.

ДРУГ (кратк., к другой). Только в выражении: друг друга, друг другу, друг другом, друг о друге (и с др. предлогами) - взаимно, один другого, один другому и т.д. или: одни других, одни другим и т.д. *Идти друг за другом (один вслед за другим, гуськом).*

2.Толковый словарь Ефремовой.

ОДИН ЗА ДРУГИМ. Друг за другом; один за одним.

3.Толковый словарь русского языка Дмитриева.

ОДИН

20.Если **люди** выходят, движутся, делают что-либо и т. п. **один за другим** или по одному, значит, не толпой, не все вместе, а по очереди, следуя **друг за другом**. 
*Один за другим пассажиры покинули вагон.*

21.Если **что-либо** следует, происходит и т. п. **одно за другим**, значит, без большого временного промежутка, перерыва между ними.

ДРУГ

Слово "друг" используется в словосочетаниях **друг друга**, друг другом и т. д. для выражения взаимности совершаемого действия. *Они любят друг друга.*

То есть тенденция различения наметилась, но не везде четко сформулирована.

Answer (score 0):

А что, простите, значит выражение " орфоэпичнее другого"? Может , вы имеете в виду насколько корректно предложение с стилистической точки зрения?

Comment: Не в коня корм.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта не подходят.  Вашу идею лучше всего выразить следующим образом: возьми сначала туза, а потом валета.

Но сам по себе вопрос интересный, и сформулировать его можно следующим образом: как определить область применения выражений  «друг за другом» и «один за другим»?

РАССМОТРИМ ПРИМЕРЫ

Ровным кругом друг за другом мы идем за шагом шаг.  Машины медленно ползли друг за другом. Он увидел на ломберном столике початую колоду, а рядом, друг за другом ― тройку, семёрку, туза.

Дни действительно бежали один за другим. Один за другим съедаю пять бутербродов с красной икрой и выпиваю три стакана кофе. Праздники следовали один за другим.

Путем чисто эмпирического наблюдения можно сделать следующие выводы (в качестве версии):

ОДИН ЗА ДРУГИМ:  простая последовательность, необходимость согласования один/одна/одно,   единственный вариант для объекта.

ДРУГ ЗА ДРУГОМ:  близкая последовательность, не нужно согласования, относится к субъекту действия (не подходит для объекта).

Comment: Кому "оба варианта не подходят"? Неужели, "уважаемому филологу", который "увидел на ломберном столике початую колоду, а рядом, друг за другом - тройку, семёрку, туза"?

Comment: Предложение, на которое вы ссылаетесь, безупречно с точки зрения семантики и грамматики, а Ваше на что похоже? Ни на что.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы в Вашем сознании я был автором предложения, которое  похоже "ни на что"?

Comment: @Галактион-у палец в рот не клади - откусит по локоть